# Keeping my ground cover planting free of unwanted vines and weeds

Tags: weed-control

Every year I have to wade into a steeply sloped tree lawn beside my driveway that is planted in Myrtle and Pacasandra to remove wild blackberry vines, a very long vined weed (maybe Creeping Charlie - not sure what it is) and other weeds and vines including poison ivy.  This is very time consuming and difficult to do.  Is there a way of controlling the unwanted vegetation and not killing my ground cover?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this, but getting rid of blackberries and poison ivy is difficult even if you're willing to kill *everything* and start over with your intentional ground cover plantings. Someone here can help you identify the "maybe Creeping Charlie" if you post a photo.

Comment: I don't have a problem with poison ivy, because I'm immune, but have to remember to wash my hands before using the door knob. I am not immune to blackberry thorns. I have this problem as well, and am awaiting the answer. My ground cover is golden sedum, which is hard to weed out of because it is is so soft.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately my solution is a lot of work.   Here is what you could do:

- remove the weeds in the spring
- cut back what you want to keep, depending on the density of planting you may have to remove some of the desired groundcover
- lay a high quality geotextile/landscape fabric.  Cut X's in the fabric when it is over a plant you want and push the fabric down to the ground to expose the plant
- cover with a mulch that does not encourage weeds like pine needles and does not slump on a slope.  Pea stone or mulch do not work: stones move downhill and mulch allows tough weeds to root