# Why doesn't my turf grow against the exterior wall?

Tags: weed-control, grass, lawn

My grass does not grow under the eve of the roof and against the brick wall even though the area receives full sun. Instead, a broadleaf grass intruder has taken over. What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 6):

It's hot and dry under the eaves. Walls of the house radiate heat and the eaves prevent all but slanting rain from wetting it.  Chances are good the soil is also more compacted.

With a different environment other plants can cope better than grass.  I will also answer the question you didn't ask...what can I do?

- put landscape fabric covered with a mulch in a three foot width from the house. I have used pea stone gravel on top a [geotextile](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/3618/499) for a long lasting low maintenance job
- improve the soil, aerate, top dress and overseed twice a year with a type of grass better suited to the conditions  (shade grass ??)
- sunnier sites can do well with a planting of shrubs that like hot and dry. [Potentilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentilla) or [Spirea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiraea_japonica) could do well.

Always remember that a basement benefits from water running away from the foundation.  Slope earth and mulches higher towards the house.